# Entity Framework Core 6 adding (or referencing when already exists) data in a Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, many-to-many

I have been struggling to get a many-to-many relationship up and running. I have followed the Microsoft's [example for EF Core 5+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many). My Join table is getting created and I can add entries to all three tables named: `SpecificationTest`, `SpecificationDeviceSpecificationTest` and `SpecificationDevice`.

I am however having some difficulties populating the join table, when the 'SpecificationDevice' already exists.

The simplified entities look as follows:

```cs
public class SpecificationTest
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SpecificationDevice> SpecificationDevices { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class SpecificationDevice
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SpecificationTest> SpecificationTests { get; set; }
}
```

The join table is automatically created, but I have added the following in the `OnModelCreating` method as well, even though it is possibly redundant:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<SpecificationTest>()
            .HasMany(a => a.SpecificationDevices)
            .WithMany(a => a.SpecificationTests);

modelBuilder.Entity<SpecificationDevice>()
            .HasMany(a => a.SpecificationTests)
            .WithMany(a => a.SpecificationDevices);
```

The DbContext also contains the following DbSets:

```
public DbSet<SpecificationTest> SpecificationTests { get; set; }
public DbSet<SpecificationDevice> SpecificationDevices { get; set; }
```

By design, every `SpecificationTest` can have multiple `SpecificationDevice`s. However, the `SpecificationDevice` table itself can only contain a single entry per unique device (Unique by combination of Serial and Name).

Adding a **new** `SpecificationDevice` works as expected. EF creates the entry in the `SpecificatonDevice` table, and correctly populates the `SpecificationDeviceSpecificationTest`  join table as well.

The problem I am having is that if the `SpecificationDevice` being added already exists, I merely want to select the ID of that device and add it to the Join table. Currently it tries to add another entry with the ID I have selected, and then throws the following exception:

> Error: System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'SpecificationDevice' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1}' is already being tracked.

Here is the code I use to try and add the entities. Disclaimer, I use the Repository pattern with a UnitOfWork to do the work, but the code comes down to the same.
Note: The `specificationTest.SpecificationDevices` collection already contains data at this stage, where the `SpecificationDevice` can be a new device or an existing device.

```cs
var existingDevices = await dbContext.SpecificationDevices.AsNoTracking().ToArrayAsync();
foreach (var specDevice in specificationTest.SpecificationDevices)
{
    var existingSpecDevice = existingDevices.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.Equals(specDevice.Name) && a.SerialNumber.Equals(specDevice.SerialNumber));

    if (existingSpecDevice is not null)
    {
        specDevice.Id = existingSpecDevice.Id;
    }
}

await dbContext.SpecificationTests.AddAsync(specificationTest);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I would expect that because I selected the ID of the existing `SpecificationDevice`, that EF will automatically populate the Join table with the correct values (`SpecificationTestId` just created and the already existing `SpecificationDeviceId`) This is not the case and I get the exception in the block quote above.

The approach of selecting the ID above works perfectly when trying to add a one-to-one entry when the unique entry already exists, but not with Many-to-many relationship.

Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: Using [this setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#join-entity-type-configuration) gives you all freedom to add just one junction class object having only two foreign key values.

Comment: I have read up on EF core and read that the ChangeTracker works with reference equality. Is this always true? If so, then only assigning the ID of the existing entity will probably not work to "reference" the existing entity?